# Return type based on parameter type

Tags: typescript, types, narrowing

My function is something like this:

```
const safeIdCastToNumber = (id: string | null | undefined) => isNil(id) ? id : Number(id)
```

Whenever I call safeIdCastToNumber I can call it with and id paramenter declared with a type union `string | null | undefined` but also some with a type union `string | undefined` since I have some non nullable ids involved.

The return type for this function is `number | null | undefined`.

I would like the return type to not include `null` if the type of the id parameter I've used does not include `null`.

E.g: if I use an id parameter of type `string | undefined` to have a return type of `number | undefined` but if I use an id parameter of type `string | null | undefined` to have a return type of `number | null | undefined`

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Well, tried that but without luck.

Comment: Then please give a [mre].

Comment: I've added a ts sample there with the error.

Comment: That's not how overloads work. You only have one overload, then the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Will post the solution here with overload functions.

```
function safeIdCastToNumber(id: string | undefined): number | undefined
function safeIdCastToNumber(id: string | null | undefined): number | null | undefined
function safeIdCastToNumber(id: string | null | undefined) => isNil(id) ? id : Number(id)
```